# Python UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

```
def blah(self, args):
    def do_blah():
        if not args:
            args = ['blah']
        for arg in args:
            print arg
```

the above raise an error at `if not args` saying UnboundLocalError: local variable 'args' referenced before assignment.

```
def blah(self, args):
    def do_blah():
        for arg in args:       <-- args here
            print arg
```

but this works despite using `args`

why is the first one not using the blah's args in `if not args:`?

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing argument from Parent function to nested function Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14678434) and [Closure in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q18274051)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is when python sees a assignment inside a function then it considers that variable as local variable and will not fetch its value from enclosing or global scope when we execute the function.

```
args = ['blah']
```

---

```
foo = 'bar'
def func():
    print foo    #This is not going to print 'bar'
    foo = 'spam'  #Assignment here, so the previous line is going to raise an error.
    print foo
func()
```

**Output:**

```
  File "/home/monty/py/so.py", line 6, in <module>
    func()
  File "/home/monty/py/so.py", line 3, in func
    print foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

Note that if `foo` is a mutable object here and you try to perform an in-place operation on it then python is not going to complain for that.

```
foo = []
def func():
    print foo
    foo.append(1)
    print foo
func()
```

**Output:**

```
[]
[1]
```

Docs: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)