# Using turtle.onclick() to change a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

Every time the turtle is clicked, how would I have it increment the variable `clicks` by 1:

```
import turtle
jeff = turtle.Turtle()
jeff.shape("turtle")
jeff.color("blue")
clicks=0


def left(x,y): 
    jeff.left(90) 
    clicks=clicks+1
    print "you have"+clicks+"clicks."


jeff.onclick(left)
```

When I type this in, on the line `clicks=clicks+1` it gives me:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clicks' referenced before
>   assignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing argument from Parent function to nested function Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678434/passing-argument-from-parent-function-to-nested-function-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `clicks` is global.  Any function that wants to *modify* a global variable has to declare that variable `global`:

```
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop

clicks = 0

def left(x, y):
    global clicks

    jeff.left(90)
    clicks += 1
    print "you have " + str(clicks) + " clicks."

jeff = Turtle()
jeff.shape("turtle")
jeff.color("blue")

jeff.onclick(left)

mainloop()
```